# Catching run time exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I know that RunTimeExceptions can be caught by Exception catch block as below.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bang");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have my own created exception class as below.

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {


    public CustomException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }


    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

But now instead of keeping Exception in catch block, i kept CustomException.But run time exception is not caught by catch block now. Why?

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                //consider here i have some logic and there is possibility that the logic might throw either runtime exception or Custom Exception
                throw new RuntimeException("Bang");
            } catch (CustomException e) {
                System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: no need to write java again in title, java tag is sufficient

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Extending Exception class does not make it is Runtime Exception. See above diagram. Also you can use polymorphic reference(superclass) to catch an subclass Exception. It does not work the other way around.

Comment: As they say `A picture paints a thousand words`

Comment: RuntimeException is not a catch-all, an Exception is, or maybe a Throwable but all three are concrete classes and don't provide a 'catch-all' interface.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `CustomException` is not a super class of `RuntimeException`. Because you are throwing `RuntimeException`, which is not the subclass of `CustomException`, the catch block is not catching it.

Comment: Aye, 755806 but CustomException does not extend RuntimeException, they have different contracts.